# How to change dnsdomainname

Tags: dns

Can anyone please help me to figure out,How can I change my localdomain name from something say `user@host.localdomian` to `user@host.something` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either edit the file `/etc/hostname` or issue `sudo echo "my_hostname" >> /etc/hostname` (replacing "my_hostname" with the name you want for the system). The file is owned by `root` so you will have to invoke `sudo` privileges to make changes to it.

Comment: I dont want edit my `host` name I want to change my `domain name` 


`from` **localhost.localdomain**

`to`

**localhost.something**

Comment: Doing as I said will accomplish that. You can enter a fictional or FQDN element as part of the `hostname` such as `myserver.mydomain.local` or `myserver.mydomain.com`. If you are using a FQDN to resolve the server, you will also need to edit `/etc/hosts` and add your FQDN to the IP address listening for those queries. Read `man hostname`.

Comment: Thank you that really helped and well sorry for miss trusting you at the first time :-)

Comment: No worries. Glad that you got it set as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead `sudo echo "my_hostname" >> /etc/hostname`, use `sudo echo "my_hostname" > /etc/hostname`.
By default that file is not empty. It has already an entry filled with your username, as a domainname. If you use `>>` instead of `>` you will append changes. Instead of actually change your hostname.domainname.